# Ruby on Rails Stored Procedure with output parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, stored-procedures

So I have the following stored procedure to create a site. I am looking to have my ruby code return the ourput parameter. What do I need to change to make it work?

```
-- FUNCTION: public.createsite(text, boolean, bigint, text, integer, text)

-- DROP FUNCTION public.createsite(text, boolean, bigint, text, integer, text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.createsite(
    sitename text,
    activeflag boolean,
    createdby bigint,
    sitedba text DEFAULT NULL::text,
    facilityid integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
    siltelogo text DEFAULT NULL::text,
    OUT siteid bigint)
    RETURNS bigint
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100.0
    VOLATILE 
AS $function$

    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO public.SITES(
            SITE_NAME, SITE_DBA, ACTIVE_FLAG, FACILITY_ID, 
            SITE_LOGO, CREATED_BY, MODIFIED_BY,
            created_at, updated_at)
        VALUES (SiteName, SiteDBA, ActiveFlag, FacilityID, SilteLogo, CreatedBy, CreatedBy, 'now', 'now')
        RETURNING SITE_ID
        INTO SiteID;
    END;

$function$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.createsite(text, boolean, bigint, text, integer, text)
    OWNER TO owner_name;
```

How Do I return the output parameter in my ruby code?

```
post 'new' do
      begin
        v1 = "site name"
        v2 = "flag"
        v3 = "1"
        v4 = "dba"
        v5 = "1"
        v6 = "logo

        sp_String = "select createsite('#{v1}', '#{v2}', '#{v3}', '#{v4}', '#{v5}','#{v6}')"
        #puts s_pString

        results =  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(s_pString)

        return results
      end
    end
```

Comment: Are you using `Mysql2` gem?

Comment: I am using Postgressql and wrote using pgAdmin. I have successfully called other stored procedures. I am having trouble with one with an output parameter